# Return list of all cell addresses within a Range

Tags: python, excel, range, openpyxl

I have a list of Ranges (loaded from an Excel workbook via openpyxl) in a list (e.g., `rng_list = ['$A$1:$A$3', '$B$1:$B$3', '$C$1:$C$3']`) and I would like to "unpack" each of those ranges into separate lists within a list of lists (i.e., `unpacked_list = [['$A$1','$A$2','$A$3'], ['$B$1','$B$2','$B$3'], ['$C$1','$C$2','$C$3']]`).

Please see the code below on what I have tried so far in a Jupyter Notebook. Any thoughts on why I am getting the error below? or if you have ideas on how I might want to approach this from a different angle, that would be much appreciated! Thanks!

```
    import os
    from openpyxl import Workbook
    from openpyxl.utils import get_column_letter

    # create temp worksheet
    wb_A = Workbook() 
    sheet_A = wb_A.create_sheet('sheetA')

    # list with Excel ranges as str items in list
    rng_list = ['$A$1:$B$10', '$C$1:$D$10', '$E$1:$F$10']
    temp_list = []
    unpacked_list = []


    for item in rng_list:
        for row in sheet_A(item): # use range from item in rng_list to iterate 
                                    through range in temp worksheet
            for cell in row:
                x = cell.row
                y = cell.column
                addr = get_column_letter(y) + str(x)
                temp_list.append(addr)
            unpacked_list.append(addr)

    # delete temp worksheet
    wb_A.remove(sheet_A)

    unpacked_list
```

I was hoping to use the range str from the list to iterate through a "dummy worksheet" created just to iterate through the cell range and capture the corresponding cell addresses within the range. I get the following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-85-13b28d369550> in <module>
     14 
     15 for item in rng_list:
---> 16     for row in sheet_A(item): # use range from item in rng_list to iterate through range in temp worksheet
     17         for cell in row:
     18             x = cell.row

TypeError: 'Worksheet' object is not callable
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Syntax! to access cells you need to use square brackets, parenthesis are used for function calls

it should be sheet_A[item]

Comment: Thanks Rahsaya Prabhakar! I was able to run code after correcting the syntax, however, the code above still did not give me my desired outcome. However, I did figure out how it needed to be modified and will post the answer separately. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

After correcting syntax error in my original code (thanks, Rahasya Prabhakar!), I modified my original code to work as needed.

Specifically, I needed to redefine the '''temp_list''' as an empty list at the start of the initial For loop, and append to the '''unpacked_list''' at the end of the initial For loop to obtain the list of list of unpacked ranges as desired.

'''
    import os
    from openpyxl import Workbook
    from openpyxl.utils import get_column_letter

```
# create temp worksheet
wb_A = Workbook() 
sheet_A = wb_A.create_sheet('sheetA')

# list with Excel ranges as str items in list
rng_list = ['$A$1:$B$10', '$C$1:$D$10', '$E$1:$F$10']
temp_list = []
unpacked_list = []


for item in rng_list:
    temp_list=[]
    for row in sheet_A[item]: # use range from item in rng_list to iterate through 
                                range in temp worksheet
        for cell in row:
            x = cell.row
            y = cell.column
            addr = get_column_letter(y) + str(x)
            temp_list.append(addr)
    unpacked_list.append(temp_list)

# delete temp worksheet
wb_A.remove(sheet_A)

print(unpacked_list)
```

'''